# Using jQuery .load() with no arguments to preload an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saw this code in a jQuery plugin (http://osvaldas.info/examples/image-lightbox-responsive-touch-friendly/imagelightbox.js) that states it preloads the next image in a lightbox.

```
if( options.preloadNext )
{
    var nextTarget = targets.eq( targets.index( target ) + 1 );
    if( !nextTarget.length ) nextTarget = targets.eq( 0 );
    $( '<img />' ).attr( 'src', nextTarget.attr( 'href' ) ).load();
}
```

I have never seen .load() without any arguments.  According to the jQuery source code, if the url parameter is blank, then it executes apply(ths, arguments).  But, since there are no arguments, what is .load() doing in this instance?  Isn't this sufficient to tell the browser to try to preload the image?

```
 $( '<img />' ).attr( 'src', nextTarget.attr( 'href' ) )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `load()` method is overloaded; it's both [a function to load a resource into an element](http://api.jquery.com/load/) (via AJAX), and it's also [a deprecated way to set/fire the "load" event handler](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) on an element.

In *this* case, the event-handler-version-of-load is being used, and all the code is doing is [triggering the "load" event on the `<img />` element](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.1.0/src/event/alias.js#L6-16) (whether or not the image has actually loaded yet).

http://jsfiddle.net/Js8s2/

... so yes, it is sufficient to just set the `src` attribute and let the browser do the rest.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate somebody else confirming my thoughts on this.